# Germanic Languages Family Tree

Tags: historical-linguistics, indo-european, germanic-languages

I really wanted to create a family tree for the Germanic Languages because I feel like the ones you find on the internet are kind of vague. I finished the family tree for the West Germanic languages, but I am in no way a professional historical linguist and just wanted to check if there are any major mistakes in my family tree. The screenshot shows the family tree, and there's also a timeline to the left.

[image]

Comment: All of those dialects you have under Middle Dutch still exist today, just as much as West Flemish does (and they're certainly older than Middle Dutch).

Comment: You could consider adding the [Yola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yola_dialect) language / Middle English dialect, extinct in the 19th century.

Comment: There is also Ostfriesisch (Eastern Frisian), which is spoken in the NW of Germany (East of the Dutch border), in the areas around Aurich.

Comment: Not sure it can be represented like this.  For example, Hunsrik almost borders on Alemannic, and there are dialects where High German and Low German fused, or Low German and Dutch.

Comment: tree diagrams inevitably fail to properly reflect the relationships present in dialect continua, such as that seen in continental west germanic

Comment: Although as a Swabian separatist I am flattered by the implication that Low German is even further from Alemannic than Jamaican English is.